# How to show currently running FPS?

Tags: benchmarks, framerate

I want to see how many frames per second (FPS) I am running at, on my computer. Is there a way to do that in Ubuntu?

Comment: Here ya go! https://nickguletskii.github.io/GLXOSD/index.html

Comment: *This version is deprecated go to:* https://glxosd.nickguletskii.com/